Why can't I get C++ date formatting to be different in different locales?
This program should, I think, produce different results if in a different locale:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char *argv[]) {
    auto now = chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto znow = chrono::zoned_time{argv[1], now};

    locale::global(locale(argv[2]));

    // These are all the locale-specific format specifiers I could find.
    cout << std::format("{:%X %x %a %b %c %p %r}", znow) << std::endl;
}

(E.g. see this)
However, it doesn't appear to (I have 885 locales installed on the machine this runs on):
$ for locale in $(locale -a); do ./locale-time "Europe/London" ${locale}; done | sort | uniq
14:51:04 10/21/24 Mon Oct Mon Oct 21 14:51:04 2024 PM 02:51:04 PM
14:51:05 10/21/24 Mon Oct Mon Oct 21 14:51:05 2024 PM 02:51:05 PM
14:51:06 10/21/24 Mon Oct Mon Oct 21 14:51:06 2024 PM 02:51:06 PM
14:51:07 10/21/24 Mon Oct Mon Oct 21 14:51:07 2024 PM 02:51:07 PM
14:51:08 10/21/24 Mon Oct Mon Oct 21 14:51:08 2024 PM 02:51:08 PM
14:51:09 10/21/24 Mon Oct Mon Oct 21 14:51:09 2024 PM 02:51:09 PM

I.e. the results only change when the time changes.
What can I do to actually see the result change in the appropriate locale?

You should specify: platform, its version and compiler.

Here is repro: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a61be4a93351c6c2

You need to use the L specifier, like
    cout << std::format("{:L%X %x %a %b %c %p %r}", znow) << std::endl;
                       //  ^

[time.format]/2:

A formatting locale is an instance of locale used by a formatting function, defined as

the "C" locale if the L option is not present in chrono-format-spec, otherwise

the locale passed to the formatting function if any, otherwise

the global locale.



